# Is orange software available for Mac with m1 chip?

Tags: orange

Hello I have the new Mac with m1 chip, do you know if I can use orange? or orange is still not available for this computers? thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can run Orange using Rosetta 2, as there's currently no official download package for Apple Silicon (Arm) machines.